# Isolate part of a string in R

Tags: regex, string, r, substring, gsub

Below is an example of a string I have ingested into R:

```
General\\Contingency\\Import\\Import_Manual\\New\\ADC170001A13_Loc.txt
```

I am trying to isolate the 'ADC170001A13' I have tried substring and also a gsub to remove everything apart from that part of the string but I get the below error:

```
Error in gsub(clean, "", TextLOCfiles) : 
invalid regular expression '\\Fs01 \DepartmentFolders$\General\Contingency\Import\Import_Manual\New\', reason 'Trailing   backslash'
In addition: Warning message:
In gsub(clean, "", TextLOCfiles) :
argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to use `regmatches`:

```
> rxmatch = regexpr('(?<=\\\\)\\w+(?=_Loc\\.)', TextLOCfiles, perl = TRUE)
> regmatches(TextLOCfiles , rxmatch)
ADC170001A13
```

`perl = TRUE` is required in order to get the zero-width assertions, as mentioned by Simon in the comments.

Comment: So with that and a gsub I am left with '\\ADC170001A13' are you saying there is no way to remove the '\\' due to this:

Comment: Perhaps I do not understand you, but R supports zero-width assertions perfectly well with `perl=TRUE` option. `(?=...)` and `(?!...)` are zero-width positive and negative lookahead assertions, whilst `(?<=...)` and `(?<!...)` are the lookbehind equivalents

Comment: e.g. `regmatches(TextLOCfiles , regexpr('(?<=\\\\)\\w+(?=\\.)', TextLOCfiles , perl = TRUE))`

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon Shame on me, I forgot to try with `perl=TRUE`.

Answer (score 2):

You can capture the needed part with `gsub` and parentheses:

```
> gsub(".*\\\\(\\w+)_.*", "\\1", TextLOCfiles)
[1] "ADC170001A13"
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a file path. If this is true then you can simply use basename() as follows:

```
sub(".txt", "", basename(TextLOCfiles))
```

Comment: I guess this is OS-dependent?

Comment: Well, it works under Linux. basename() should work under Windows too. So provided that the path and OS you are using are consistent then it should be okay. Would be interested to know whether it works under Windows... pretty sure it will.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
library( tools )
basename( file_path_sans_ext( TextLOCfiles ) )
```

or without addon packages:

```
sub( "\\.[^.]*$", "", basename( TextLOCfiles ) )
```

These solutions do not require that you know the file name or extension and also work if there is no extension.